# using load() to load page that also uses jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-plugins

I'm trying to load a page that is basically an edit form inside a
dialog (ui.dialog).  I can load this page fine from an external (I'm
using asp.net) page.

The problem is that inside of my "popup" form, I need to `$(function()
{my function here});` syntax to do some stuff when the page loads,
along with registering some `.fn` extensions for some dynamic dropdowns
using ajax calls.

I have created my `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">` but
I don't think these are being included, and also my `$(function)` is not
being called.

Is this possible to do or do I need to find another way of
accomplishing what I need to do?

Comment: Are you saying you need the jQuery document load event in the popup form layer to execute? So, in other words, you are loading a full HTML page into a DIV popup, but that page you are loading is not executing the load event?

Comment: You need to clarify your question  - give us some sample code (calling the page, being called etc.) so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to load that form via AJAX you could to do all the Javascript stuff in  $.ajax callback itself.
So, you load the popup form like this:

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   success: function(text) {
       // insert text into container
       // the code from $(function() {});
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The script isn't getting run because the document's ready event has already been fired. Remove your code from within the

```
$()
```

Comment: if ready is already fired, a call to  $(function() {}) will fire immediately

Answer (score 0):

Use the livequery plugin.

It allows you to bind events to elements that might be loaded later: http://brandonaaron.net/docs/livequery/